# How do I create a model in cakephp3 which is not ORM?

Tags: cakephp, model, controller, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to create a model in CakePHP3.0 which allows me to check if a view exists by name and if so gets me the column names in that view.

In src/model/table I have created a ViewQuerier.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;

class ViewQuerier {

    public function checkViewExists($viewName = null) {
        $connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');

        if ( $viewName == null ) {
            return false;
        }
        $sql = "SELECT TABLE_NAME
                FROM information_schema.tables
                WHERE TABLE_TYPE like 'VIEW' AND TABLE_SCHEMA = database() 
                                             AND TABLE_NAME = :VIEW_NAME";

        $result = $connection()
                ->execute( $sql, ['VIEW_NAME' => $viewName ] )
                ->fetch('assoc');

        if (count($result))
        {
            $sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM :VIEW_NAME";

            return $connection()
                ->execute($sql, ['VIEW_NAME' => $viewName ] )
                ->fetch('assoc');
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

In the controller I  have the following loading the model:

```
public function initialize()
{
    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
    $this->loadModel('ViewQuerier');
}
```

And then calling the method like so:

```
public function view($viewname)
{
    $this->viewName = $viewname;
    $this->ViewQuerier->checkViewExists($this->viewName);
}
```

The error I get is:

**Unknown method "checkViewExists"**

What have I done wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a "model" (table) that could be loaded using `loadModel()`, it's just a class that happens to live in the `Model\Table` namespace.

Firstly I'd suggest that you place that class somewhere else, it's not a table class, it's loosely related to the model layer and only provides utility functionality, something like `Model\Utility` would probably be a better place.

That being said, you'd just use it like any other class and instantiate it manually.

```
use App\Model\Utility\ViewQuerier;

// ...

$viewQuerier = new ViewQuerier();
$viewQuerier->checkViewExists($this->viewName);
```

On a side note, given the fact that the method actually doesn't touch the instance, you could maybe make it static instead.